# How can I precompile data with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a web app that uses some static (rarely changed) data in JSON format. JSON is just an array of objects, and I'm making some transformations to create more usable map for search and some other manipulations. The app is built using Webpack

Code looks like this:

```
import entries from './entries.json'

export const entriesMap = entries.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  // some transforming code here
}, {})
```

The problem is that this runs every time on app loading, and actually always doing the same work.

My question: is there a way to tell Webpack to execute this code on compile-time, so it will automatically bundle the application with `entriesMap` already evaluated?

If yes, is there a reason to do so, or is it better to leave it like this?